How to avoid square root in iterative calculation?
I have a function:
$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2 - 2y - 1$
x[n+1]^2 = x[n]^2 - 2*y - 1

I want to iterate the function over the Y-axis at integer intervals of 1. I.e. the "y" will always be incremented by 1. But the starting value can be a non integer value.
I need to calculate the x[n+1], but that would require me to calculate square root of x[n+1]^2, which is a bad thing in my case, as I want the algorithm to be as fast as possible.
How do I avoid having to calculate the square root?

Perhaps you can keep calculating $x_{n+1}^2$ until desired iteration, and then at the end take the square root?!?

@Anton That won't work in my case, as I need each and every one of those output values.

"I want to iterate the function over the Y-axis at integer intervals of 1." What does this mean? What is "the function"? You have an iterative expression (from $x_n$ you get $x_{n+1}$); when you say "the 'y' will always be incremented by 1," do you mean each time you add $1$ to $n$ you also add $1$ to $y$? When you say, "But the starting value can be a non integer value," do you mean the starting value of $y$? What's the starting value of $x$?

I doubt there is a way to reduce the formula $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_n^2 - 2y - 1}$ to a formula without a square root, so I think the only way is to approximate the sequence. Newton's method for square root approximation is, if we want to find the square root of a number $y$,
$$x \approx \frac{1}{2}(x_{guess} + \frac{y}{x_{guess}})$$.
We can use this to get an approximation for $x_{n+1}$ by
$$x_{n+1} \approx \frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{x_{n+1}^2}{x_n})$$
and our guess is that $x_{n+1}$ is close to $x_n$, and we compute $x_{n+1}^2$ directly from the formula and not from an approximation. If the initial value of $y$ as defined in your sequence is small, then this approximation works well enough I think. For example, given that $y_0 = 0.1$ and $x_0^2 = 65$, then the first 9 values of the sequence are:
7.987490219086343
7.784600182411425
7.576278769950324
7.3620649277223835
7.141428428542849
6.913754406977441
6.678323142825598
6.434283176858163
6.180614856144976

While the approximations are :
7.987490219086343
7.7871769847518895
7.57913462240453
7.365173412707604
7.14482697838911
6.917490993840937
6.682457680984754
6.438891555050646
6.185794851228546

My answer is, of course, useless if you want a completely exact solution. It is also useless if $y_0$ is large, but if $y_0$ is large, then after a few iterations $x_n^2$ will be negative, and so $x_n$ can't be a real number.

"a completely exact solution" is only possible for perfect squares. But maybe your idea was an approximation exact to the precission of your system or calculator.
